# This page isn’t working // I think it's my .env?

Tags: craft3, installation

Been struggling for hours to solve this with no solution and I'm under a deadline for a client. Any help would be so amazing.

Here's what happened:

- I set up the initial craft project with craft create
- This got pushed to Github and other devs have been continuing work
- We were collaborating just fine on the project back and fourth with changes.
- In my development I somehow deleted my `.env` file.
- Now - I can't get my `/admin/dashboard` to show up or the craft site at all.
- I've been playing with the settings in the `.env` I've been going back and fourth with the `/phpMyAdmin/?lang=en` page trying to set up and link a database.
- It seems: the project is fine, the database is fine, but I can't seem to link my database and the craft project and get craft to run at all.

Any tips? Any direction? I am just seeing this in the browser:

```
This page isn’t working localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

Help please! Thanks.

FYI - I am on MacOS running MAMP (From my applications folder) and I have PHP 7.2.11 all installed and running.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's actually JUST my security key that's gone and I can't figure out how to regenerate or recreate it. That first env is gone.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the `.env` file holds the environmental-specific settings/"secrets" that Craft needs to run. So you'll need to recreate it; here's a template:

https://github.com/craftcms/craft/blob/master/.env.example

More information can be found here: [Environmental Configuration](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/environments.html)

Comment: So helpful! But how do I regenerate the security key for this project?

Comment: If no one else is using it, you can just generate any old random number you want to use for it. But if you're working with other devs, I'm sure one of them has the security key that you're using in their `.env` that they can give to you?

Comment: Unfortunately I still can't get this thing running. It runs perfectly on the other developers machines and it was running on mine at one point. I got the .env from my other team member and it didn't get this thing running. I'm really desperate to find a solution on this. I appreciate the help though! I've got to keep digging.

Comment: As well, I was able to spin up a brand new craft project without any issues. I can sign in and everything. Very odd that this project just won't run.